# Early 2011 MacBook Pro 17" to 30" cinema display

Tags: macbook-pro, cinema-display

I have a 17" MacBook Pro and a 30" Apple cinema display.  The best resolution I can get on the cinema display is 1280x800.  Is there a way to get better resolution?

Comment: Both your MBP and Display are capable of 2560 by 1440 pixels resolution.  What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: What video connections are you using? What vintage of MBP 17" do you own. The last 17" MBP (Early '11) had Thunderbolt DV out (capable of 2 T-bolt ext displays); whilst the first 17" MBP ('06) had a Dual-link DVI.

Answer (score 1):

Your particular model of MacBook Pro was equipped with an AMD Radeon HD 6750M dedicated graphics card and on-board Intel HD 3000 graphics card. In terms of VRAM you have 1 GB available on the AMD and 384 MB on the Intel (shared with main memory).

**This combination is capable of up to 2560 x 1600 pixels on external displays *that do not require a dual-link DVI connection*.**

If you're finding that the highest available resolution is 1280 x 800 instead of 2560 x 1600, this is likely due to you using a single-link DVI connection on a display that requires a dual-link DVI connection. Unfortunately, the 30" Apple Cinema Display is one such monitor.

You would need to connect this display to a dual-link DVI port to access the higher resolutions available on the 30" display. However, your model MacBook Pro does not provide a dual-link DVI connection without an appropriate adaptor and that is why it's not supporting the 30" Apple Cinema Display at its native 2560 x 1600 resolution.

**For best results you will need to use a [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB571LL/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter).**

You should refer to this [info](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201927) on Apple's website. Also of interest may be this [Mini DisplayPort adapter FAQs](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204149) page.